# Rerun StateFlow When Filter Needs to Change?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow, kotlin-stateflow

I have a `StateFlow` containing a simple list of strings. I want to be able to filter that list of Strings. Whenever the filter gets updated, I want to push out a new update to the StateFlow.

```
class ResultsViewModel(
    private val api: API
) : ViewModel() {

  var filter: String = ""
  val results: StateFlow<List<String>> = api.resultFlow()
        .stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.Eagerly, emptyList())
}
```

It's easy enough to stick a `map` onto `api.resultFlow()`:

```
  val results: StateFlow<List<String>> = api.resultFlow()
        .map { result ->
            val filtered = mutableListOf<String>()
            for (r in result) {
                if (r.contains(filter)) {
                   filtered.add(r)
                }
            }
            filtered
        }
        .stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.Eagerly, emptyList())
```

But how do I get the flow to actually emit an update when `filter` changes? Right now, this only works with whatever the initial value of `filter` is set to.

Comment: What's the use of the `map` here? And where do you use the filter at all?

Comment: Whoops! I left of the actualy filtering condition. Fixed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could have the filter update another StateFlow that is combined with the other one. By the way, there's `filter` function that is easier to use than manually creating another list and iterating to get your results.

```
class ResultsViewModel(
    private val api: API
) : ViewModel() {

  private val filterFlow = MutableStateFlow("")

  var filter: String
    get() = filterFlow.value
    set(value) {
        filterFlow.value = value
    }

  val results: StateFlow<List<String>> = 
    api.resultFlow()
      .combine(filterFlow) { list, filter ->
          list.filter { it.contains(filter) }
      }
      .stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.Eagerly, emptyList())
}
```