# Unable to Filter Data in ViewModel - Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel

I am facing issues filtering data in a ViewModel when fetching data from an API. I have a ViewModel (CharacterViewModel) that retrieves data using a getCharactersUseCase. I want to filter this data based on a character ID and observe the filtered result in a Composable (CharacterDetailScreen). However, I am not getting the expected result.

CharacterViewModel

```
  @HiltViewModel
  class CharacterViewModel @Inject constructor(
   private val getCharactersUseCase: GetCharactersUseCase
  ) : ViewModel() {
   private val _characterState: MutableStateFlow<PagingData<Character>> =
       MutableStateFlow(value = PagingData.empty())
   private val _characterDetailsState: MutableStateFlow<Character?> = MutableStateFlow(null)

   val charactersState: MutableStateFlow<PagingData<Character>> get() = _characterState
   val characterDetailsState: MutableStateFlow<Character?> get() = _characterDetailsState

   init {
       getCharacters()
   }

   private fun getCharacters() {
       viewModelScope.launch {
           getCharactersUseCase.execute(Unit)
               .distinctUntilChanged()
               .cachedIn(viewModelScope)
               .collect {
                   _characterState.value = it
               }
       }
   }
   fun getCharacterDetails(characterID: String) {
       Log.i("character"," character from viewmodel received id= ${characterID}")
       // Collect the latest charactersState and then filter the character
       viewModelScope.launch {
           charactersState.collect { characters ->
               characters
                   .filter { it.id == characterID }
                   .map { character ->
                       Log.i("character"," character from viewmodel id= ${character.id}")
                       _characterDetailsState.value = character
                   }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

CharacterDetailScreen

```
 @Composable
 fun CharacterDetailScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    viewModel: CharacterViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
     characterId: String
 )
 {
    // Collect character details state
    val characterDetailsState by viewModel.characterDetailsState.collectAsState()

    LaunchedEffect(characterDetailsState) {
        viewModel.getCharacterDetails(characterId)
    }
    // Use LaunchedEffect to trigger the getCharacterDetails call when the Composable is first       launched
    CharacterDetailsItem(characterDetailsState, characterId)
    }
```

CharacterDetailsItem

```
   
    @Composable
    fun CharacterDetailsItem(character_: Character?, characterId: String){
    Log.i("character"," character from details item ${character_?.name}")
    val character by remember { mutableStateOf(character_) }
    Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 8.dp)) {
        Card(
            colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
                containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceVariant,
            ),
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()

        ) {
            Column {
                Text(
                    text = characterId,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(16.dp),
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                )
                character?.name?.let {
                    Text(
                        text = it,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(16.dp),
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    )
                }
                character?.gender?.let {
                    Text(
                        text = it,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(16.dp),
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

Logcat

```
2023-11-17 12:01:19.709  5486-5486  character               com.starwars.app                     I   character from details item null
2023-11-17 12:01:19.740  5486-5486  character               com.starwars.app                     I   character from viewmodel received id= 631a02dc-ecf2-4636-8e59-d180766e52cf
2023-11-17 12:01:19.760  5486-5486  character               com.starwars.app                     I   character from details item null
2023-11-17 12:01:20.472  5486-5486  character               com.starwars.app                     I   character from details item null
2023-11-17 12:01:20.524  5486-5486  character               com.starwars.app                     I   character from details item null
```

I've provided the code snippets for the ViewModel (CharacterViewModel), Composable (CharacterDetailScreen), and the Composable used to display details (CharacterDetailsItem). I would appreciate any insights into what might be causing the issue with the filtering logic in the ViewModel.

What I have tried:

1st:

```
    fun getCharacterDetails(characterID: String) {
    Log.i("character", " character from viewmodel received id= ${characterID}")
    // Collect the latest charactersState and then filter the character
    viewModelScope.launch {
     _characterDetailsState.value = Character("213","bday","e","g","h","hi","name","skin")
      
    }
}
```

this way I am able to set and get valure but not from charactersState or  _characterState filtered value.

2nd:

```
@Composable
fun CharacterDetailScreen(
navController: NavController,
viewModel: CharacterViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
characterId: String
) {
// Collect character details state
val characterPagingItems: LazyPagingItems<Character> = 
viewModel.charactersState.collectAsLazyPagingItems()

val selectedCharacter = characterPagingItems.itemSnapshotList
    .find { it?.id == characterId }

// Call CharacterDetailsItem when selectedCharacter is not null
selectedCharacter?.let { character ->
    CharacterDetailsItem(character, characterId) //this composable 
  //gets recomposed with null values
}
Text(text = "first") //this text stays

}
```

My DI character module:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
object CharacterModule {
@Provides
@ViewModelScoped
fun providesCharacterRemoteDataSource(
    api: StarWarsApi
): CharacterRemoteDataSource {
    return CharacterRemoteDataSourceImpl(api)
}

@Provides
@ViewModelScoped
fun providesCharacterRepository(
    characterRemoteDataSource: CharacterRemoteDataSource,
    starWarsDatabase: StarWarsDatabase
): CharacterRepository {
    return CharacterRepositoryImpl(characterRemoteDataSource, 
starWarsDatabase)
}

@Provides
@ViewModelScoped
fun providesGetCharactersUseCase(
    characterRepository: CharacterRepository
): GetCharactersUseCase {
    return GetCharactersUseCase(characterRepository)
}
@Provides
@ViewModelScoped
fun providesGetCharacterDetailsUseCase(
    characterRepository: CharacterRepository
): GetCharacterDetailsUseCase {
    return GetCharacterDetailsUseCase(characterRepository)
}
@Provides
@ViewModelScoped
fun provideCharacterDetailsViewModel(
    getCharactersUseCase: GetCharactersUseCase
): CharacterViewModel {
    return CharacterViewModel(getCharactersUseCase)
}
}
```

Comment: what logs do you get in Logcat ?

Comment: @Rob I log that I have set in ViewModel filter function is never called. I think I am doing Something wrong after filter fun.

Comment: try to to filter (.filter { it.id == characterID }) directly on the flow, and map also on the flow, and emit value to your stateFlow of viewModel in the collect block

Comment: still does not work.

Comment: Can you check if your use case getCharactersUseCase.execute(Unit) is working properly and you are receiving a list of characters from it?

Comment: @Ankush Yes, I am getting the list of characters properly and I am showing a list in the character screen and onclick a character list item I open the character details screen.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not collect the state inside `ViewModel`. If you want to filter the state list by search query.

You might want to consider a similar solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72311648/7805359

Comment: Thank you for suggesting an alternative approach. However, upon implementing it, I encountered an issue with passing filtered values from the `characterDetailsScreen` to the `characterItem` composables. After a certain period, it appears that the passed value is lost. I suspect this issue arises because the ViewModel scope becomes inaccessible for the `characterDetailsScreen` over time.

Note: I am utilizing a single Dependency Injection (DI) module and ViewModel for both the Character Screen and Character Details Screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this
fun getCharacterDetails(characterID: String) {
    Log.i("character"," character from viewmodel received id= 
     ${characterID}")
    // Collect the latest charactersState and then filter the character
    viewModelScope.launch {
        charactersState.collect { characters ->
            val filteredCharacters = characters.filter { it.id == 
            characterID }
            if (filteredCharacters.isNotEmpty()) {
                _characterDetailsState.value = filteredCharacters.first()
            } else {
                _characterDetailsState.value = null
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun CharacterDetailScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    viewModel: CharacterViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
    characterId: String
) {
    // Call getCharacterDetails directly
    viewModel.getCharacterDetails(characterId)

    // Collect character details state
    val characterDetailsState by 
    viewModel.characterDetailsState.collectAsState()

    // Use characterDetailsState in your composable
    CharacterDetailsItem(characterDetailsState, characterId)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Tried this, but it does not work.